# Как распарсить url строку в http запросе в golang?

Tags: golang, http

Пытаюсь извлечь метод из url запроса, данные получаю, не могу получить метод.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/api/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        name := r.URL.Query().Get("a")
        age := r.URL.Query().Get("b")
        met := r.URL.Query().Get("add")
        fmt.Println("a = ", name, "b= ", age, "met = ", " ", met)
    })
    fmt.Println("Server is listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":10443", nil)
}
```

Запрос:

http://localhost:10443/api/add?a=1&b=15

Хочу получить метод add (3 символа) , который идет после "/api/"

Comment: что значит метод add? у вас эндпоинт /api/add, а не api. значит ваш хэндлер не сработает на вызов  /api/add,

Comment: Возможно не лучшее решение, решил так:     met := r.URL.String()
  fmt.Println("a = ", name, "b= ", age, "met = ", met[5:8])

Comment: лучше сделать еще одним параметром

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` - это та часть URL, которая идёт после знака вопроса `?`

В вашем случае `add` не входит в `query`, а является частью `path`. Извлечь "имя файла" из URL можно методом `path.Base`. Пример разбора вашего URL:

```go
package main

import (
        "net/url"
        "path"
)

func main() {
        rawReq := "http://localhost:10443/api/add?a=1&b=15"
        u,_ := url.Parse(rawReq);
        println("Path: ", u.Path)
        println("Method name: ", path.Base(u.Path))
}
```

Результат:

```
Path:  /api/add
Method name:  add
```